# Merge tags [cecil], [mono-cecil] and [mono.cecil] on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

- `cecil× 12`
- `mono.cecil× 8`
- `mono-cecil× 3`

I think `Mono.Cecil` is a good choice since Mono.Cecil is the official name of the project and cecil alone is somewhat of an "insider acronym"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and merged these per your suggestion.

Comment: Cool, thanks a million. The number of questions affected has grown in the meantime, so I was reluctant to editing all myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

1. Manually retag 5 questions with cecil to mono.cecil
2. Add synonyms on the mono.cecil tag to cecil / mono-cecil
3. Wait for people to upvote it or mods to approve